# Absolute positioning not working in wordpress

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this text to go inside the picture. For some reason it doesn't work when I add it into WordPress. Seems to work fine in JS fiddle which I've attached below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[Screenshot of what's happening on WP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YuXG.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/tdh3euue/

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-1015" 
src="https://www.thesurebettor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/what-is-
matched-betting-1.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="431" />
<div class="text-wrapper"><p>What is matched</p><p>betting?</p>

</div>
</div>

.outer-wrapper {
position: relative;
}

.text-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 52px;
 font-weight: bold;  
}
```

Comment: what does `.aligncenter` do?

Comment: I'm assuming you need to do something like this. use `left: 50%; transform: translateX();` and the value you pass to `translateX()` would be `-50%` for the text to be absolutely centered over the image, or a different value if you want to offset the text a little. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bWQGYP

Comment: If your code is working on fiddle but not in real case, you may have some wordpress CSS rules that interfer with your own. Using some web tools, like FireBug, you can check if other rules are applied to your elements, and then try to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

From your image I think you have a center align to outer-wrapper that's why the text is shifted.

Here I used `left: calc((100% - 750px)/2 + 35px);` since your img are fixed to 750px width, I use that calc to set the correct left as 35px from the left edge of the img.

Also using `@media (max-width: 750px)` if the screen is less than 750px, which the calc will return a value less than 35px, we don't want that so, this media query will help you set the left to 35px if the screen is less than 750px wide.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 750px)/2 + 35px);
  top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .text-wrapper {
    left: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">

  <img class="aligncenter wp-image-1015" src="https://www.thesurebettor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/what-is-matched-betting-1.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="431" />
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <p>What is matched</p>
    <p>betting?</p>

  </div>
</div>
```